# Optimizing for "sudden" change in angular momentum

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, jerk

I'm trying to create an elaborate impossible-to-juggle juggling club, by triggering a sudden change in angular momentum via a mechanism inside of the juggling club while it is in mid-air. The mechanism is going to be a torsion spring attached to a flywheel. For the prototype, I will manually wind up the torsion spring ahead of time, and I have a release mechanism that will be triggered via a small hobby servo controlled by an arduino.

I would like to do some calculations to make sure that my setup will produce the sufficient unexpected angular momentum change, however, I'm not sure what exactly I should be optimizing for. I could try to just maximize the total change in angular momentum (angular impulse), but that doesn't necessarily account for the "suddenness". I could try to make sure that the total amount of time for the angular momentum change is minimized, however, I was thinking that maybe it would be better to optimize for maximum jerk. Or maybe jerk over time? I've never been able to wrap my head around jerk. What should I be optimizing for?

Answer (score 0):

For maximum effect you will want to maximize the mass and radius of the flywheel and the torque exerted by the spring. You will need to decide whether you want the flywheel to be set spinning or allowed to oscillate.  Its axis should be perpendicular to the long axis of the club.  Your biggest problem will building a mechanism which can withstand being dropped.

Comment: The flywheel radius is limited to about 3 inches due to space constraints. The mass of the flywheel needs to be minimized and will probably need to be about 100 grams or less. I plan to wind my own torsion spring with music wire. It is limited to 3/4 inch diameter and 15 inches in length, but the wire gauge can be any size (I have bought some 12 gauge music wire to start out with). I also have a one way bearing for the flywheel so that it only spins in one direction.

Comment: The torsion spring will run along the long axis of the club, but I also have a 90 degree drive kit that will convert the rotation of the torsion spring to allow the flywheel to be perpendicular.

Comment: Basically the only things that I have much control over given the space requirements, are the gauge of the music wire (which affects the torque of the spring), and the weight of the flywheel (which I want to minimize).

Comment: You're right about the mechanism needing to withstand being dropped. I created a design in fusion 360 CAD software that I think will be fairly sturdy, but I won't know for sure until I test out the prototype.

Comment: Oops! I meant to say that the flywheel is limited to 3 inches diameter, not radius. I might be able to push that to 4 inches with a larger bulb (the non-handle part of the club), but anything larger than that would be too big for a normal sized juggling club.